# Getting incompatible integer to pointer error

Tags: objective-c

Im getting the error `incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning unsigned int from a function with result type NSUInteger *`

I'm not sure what is that mean since they are kind of the same, no..? sorry im totally a newbie, here is my code for my PlayingCards deck class:

PlayingCards.h

```
#import "Card.h"

@interface PlayingCards : Card

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;

+(NSArray *) validSuit;

+(NSUInteger *) maxRank;


@end
```

PlayingCards.m

```
#import "PlayingCards.h"

@implementation PlayingCards

@synthesize suit = _suit;

//modifying the contents getter so it will return array with the ranks and rank+suit 
-(NSString *) contents {

    NSArray *cardsRank = [PlayingCards rankStrings];

    return [cardsRank[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
}

//creating a method to make sure we get validated suits
+(NSArray *) validSuit {

    return @[@"♠",@"♣",@"♥",@"♦"];
}

//creating calss method to validate the rank
+(NSArray *) rankStrings {

    return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
}

//creating a new setter for suit to make sure we get the valitated suits, uding the validateSuit method
-(void) setSuit:(NSString *)suit {

    if ([[PlayingCards validSuit] containsObject:suit]) {
        _suit = suit;
    }
}

//creating new getter for suit to make sure its not empty
-(NSString *) suit {

    return _suit? _suit: @"?";
}

//creating a class method to make sure when user set the rank he will will
+(NSUInteger *) maxRank {

    return [self rankStrings].count - 1;

}

//creating a new setter to the renk to make sure the rank is validates 
-(void) setRank:(NSUInteger)rank {

    if (rank <= [PlayingCards maxRank]) {

        _rank = rank;
    }
}

@end
```

please help me to figure this out, its in the line (in the .m file):

```
+(NSUInteger *) maxRank {

    return [self rankStrings].count - 1;

}
```

And effecting on the line:

```
-(void) setRank:(NSUInteger)rank {

    if (rank <= [PlayingCards maxRank]) {

        _rank = rank;
    }
}
```

With another error

`order comparison between pointer and integer`

thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the `*` anywhere you are using `NSUInteger`. `NSUInteger` is a basic type, not a class.

Comment: Or at least malloc a pointer to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you have tried to accidentally use a pointer where you should not. Or didn't use a pointer where you should have. 
Your class method is returning a pointer to your NSUInteger. Remove the *